# Pullup bar for door or station?

Tags: pull-ups

I'm getting into bodyweight training and looking to buy a pullupbar.

What do you guys recommend me to do: buy a pullupbar for in my door or a station?

Also recommendations on which pullupbar (which product) are welcome!

I got some space for a station but it can't be too big (I'd say 1m by 1m

Comment: To avoid your question being closed, I would do a couple things. 1- Edit out the question for a recommendation, as that is off topic on most SE sites. 2- Outline your program (i.e. what you intend to use the bar for) and any constraints (available space, etc). That makes it about the equipment in context of a program, rather than a "which should I buy" which would be off topic.

Comment: Consider some gymnastic rings if you have a place to put them up. Pullups, dips, levers, etc.

Comment: If you have space station gives more flexibility - in terms of grip. A specially when compared to telescopic one. Bar for door takes less space, easier for setup. On the other hand - not all door-frames can handle pullup bar. Wooden frames can be destroyed by both telescopic and that other attached bar.